# Where are all of the secrets in the Hangar - E1M1?

Tags: doom

I have played through the Hangar level of the first episode of DOOM now several times, but have not yet been able to complete the level with 100% in Kills, Items and Secrets. I am getting outside to pick up the blue power armour, and running back through to ensure that I'm not missing any items and kills;

[image]

I am going to suspect that the missing items are in the same places as the missing secrets, so where are all of the secrets in the Hangar - E1M1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Doom wiki](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/E1M1:_Hangar_(Doom)#Secrets):

[image: Map of the Hangar]

> 1. In the corridor at the end of the zig-zag room, a portion of the west wall is colored differently and has a corpse lying next to it **(G)**. Activate the wall to gain access to the courtyard with the blue armor. (sector 68)
> 2. After having entered the dark room with the exit door, return to the zig-zag room. The platform with the Imp(s) has now been lowered, yielding access to a secret room **(H)** containing a shotgun. (sector 69)
> 3. [Added in version 1.2]  After opening secret #2, walk toward the north end of the zig-zag room. As you cross the shadow line **(I)**, a lift will lower in the shotgun alcove **(J)**, visible from where you are standing. Run and you can catch it before it goes up. At the end of the hallway is a fake see-through wall, the first such wall in the game. (sector 70)

Answer (score 2):

It has been a long LONG while, but in the room where the shootable door to the blue armor is, there is an elevator where the imp was. Listen for it to lower. I think that when you move toward the exit by opening a door, it will lower. If the imp is still alive, he'll follow you.

Once that is down, if you backtrack to the entrance to that room, you can RUSH back across to this secret area and all the way in and to the left, (i think) there is a secondary secret area w/elevator. You can actually hear it triggering if you listen closely.